# Is it possible in SAS to assign values from one column to a macro variables from another column

Tags: variables, sas, sas-macro

I have lost may head already finding the solution to my problem.

I have two columns **VarName** and **VarDate**

I want to assign values of **VarDate** to macro variables in column **VarName** not naming them separately one by one.

Result should be 14 macro variables with assigned values.

***For example:***

if I would write %put &A_10; It should return me value 14/06/2020

if I would write %put &A_11; It should return me value 12/06/2020

if I would write %put &G_11; It should return me value 31/12/2021

```
data have;
input VarName $ VarDate :ddmmyy10.;
format VarDate ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
A_10 14/06/2020
A_11 12/06/2020
B_10 30/06/2020
B_11 30/06/2020
C_10 31/05/2020
C_11 29/05/2020
D_10 30/04/2020
D_11 30/04/2020
E_10 31/03/2020
E_11 31/03/2020
F_10 29/02/2020
F_11 28/02/2020
G_10 31/12/2021
G_11 31/12/2021
;
run;
```

Comment: I have a sneaky feeling you won't need macro at all for whatever you plan on doing.  What have you tried or looked at that made your head wobble ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It work fine. The end of log in the comment:

```
data have;
input VarName $ VarDate :ddmmyy10.;
format VarDate ddmmyy10.;
datalines;
A_10 14/06/2020
A_11 12/06/2020
B_10 30/06/2020
B_11 30/06/2020
C_10 31/05/2020
C_11 29/05/2020
D_10 30/04/2020
D_11 30/04/2020
E_10 31/03/2020
E_11 31/03/2020
F_10 29/02/2020
F_11 28/02/2020
G_10 31/12/2021
G_11 31/12/2021
;
run;

data _null_;
    set have;
        call symput(VarName,put(VarDate,ddmmyys10.));
run;

%put &A_10.;
%put &A_11.;
.
.
.
.
/*results in the log:

4116  %put &A_10.;
14/06/2020
4117  %put &A_11.;
12/06/2020

*/
```

Comment: That was exactly what I needed, it was so simple and I had tried too complicated things. Thank you a lot.